# Order by sequence of values in set

Tags: mysql, find-in-set

How can I have concatenated names ordered by their sequence in the set (it is a variable where I have ids comma separated like this "4,3,2")? So far the names are being ordered by id "2,3,4". This is my subquery.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ',') FROM table t WHERE find_in_set(t.id, "4,3,2") > 0
```

Comment: Storing `id`'s as csv is very bad database design.

Comment: It is but this time I need it that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order by` in `group_concat` function to order the names as in same order you have ids in `find_in_set`,`find_in_set` returns the index of matched value like for id => 4 index will be one for id=> 3 index will be 2 so you can order your result by using the result of `find_in_set`

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(t.name ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, "4,3,2") SEPARATOR ',' )
FROM t 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t.id, "4,3,2") > 0
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3dfd2/3)